# Where to bootstrap IoC for class library dotnet core

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, ioc-container

Im am using dotnet core.I am trying to implement repository pastern.

My  solution is set up in following way

1. Web project
2. Repository Project that is `class library`

In my repository project i am trying to make all my User calls using Mongo. Since `class library` project dont have an entry point like web-project `startup.cs`.

My questions is how do i inject `IMongoClient` with connection string into a repository class

For my Di i am using Structruremap

For Example

```
public class UserRepo
{
private readonly IMongoClient _client;

UserRepo(IMongClient client)
{
_client = client;
}
}
```

Comment: **unclear what you're asking**. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: edited my question. thank you.